# how to send CTRL-ALT-Fn to virtual box guest Linux?

Tags: virtualbox, virtual-machine

This should be a simple question:

- **Host OS:** Arch Linux
- **Guest OS:** Arch Linux (GNOME)

How can I send <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> to my Guest Linux OS?

Comment: If you are at the console, you can also use `chvt n` (where `n` is from your `Ctrl + Alt + Fn`). Using that command in a GUI (e.g. tty7) requires root privileges to get a console fd.

Comment: For keyword search purposes: **FreeBSD** (the accepted answer is good for both types of OS).

Answer (score 30, accepted):

<kbd>Host</kbd> + <kbd>F1</kbd>, default <kbd>Host</kbd> key is <kbd>Right Ctrl</kbd>.

Comment: If `host key` bind to `Alt` it doesn't work. Go to `File => Preferences` and rebind to `Right Ctrl`!!

Comment: @gavenkoa new problem... my keyboard doesn't have right ctrl!! :(

Comment: @Kent, just rebind this in settings to other unused key.

Comment: Just in case anyone needs, if one needs to send **Ctrl + Alt** to a guest machine (just those two keys together, without a third one), one can simply press **Ctrl + Alt** (the wanted keys themselves). https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?f=8&t=69058

Comment: VirtualBox 5.1.26 does not have Host + Fn defined to anything.  When I look at the Input->Keyboard Settings window, Virtual Machine tab, I see no *Shortcut* defined for Host + Fn.  And no *Name* for anything to "Insert Ctrl-Alt-Fn".  And Host + Fn does not switch to the nth virtual terminal for any Fn I try.

Answer (score 3):

Long answer: The quickest path to the answer is actually VirtualBox's excellent manual (yes, some people still write those things these days). You can open the manual with the menu Help -> Contents... and type "ctrl+alt+f" in the search field: this will position you right to the chapter "Typing special characters", with the answer you're looking for. Otherwise, you can also read it online: https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch01.html#specialcharacters

Short answer: We tend to rely too much on stackexchange, while we just need to RTFM to find a quality answer. (me included :)

Comment: +1; I never take Stack Exchange as a primary source.  I use it to look up a quick answer, *and then I look in the docs* to read the official documentation of the feature or option or whatever that was described in the answer.  (I'm discovering as I deliver professional trainings that I'm in a tiny minority....)

Answer (score 1):

If you have vnc installed, you can run VirtualBox in a vnc session.  Then use a vncviewer (e.g., using the <kbd>F8</kbd> context menu in tigervnc's vncviewer) to set the <kbd>Alt</kbd> key in a pressed state.  Then manually enter <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Fn</kbd> to switch to the n'th virtual terminal.  "Unpress" the Alt key via your vncviewer.

Not the quickest method, but it works when other methods don't work (e.g., <kbd>Host</kbd> + <kbd>Fn</kbd> did not work for me in VirtualBox 5.1.26).