# Cannot log into CentOS 7 as root

Tags: centos, virtualbox

I have a CentOS 7.0 VM, running under VirtualBox. Set it up a few months back, nice to get it back, but not crucial.

I have successfully followed the [instructions from RedHat](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/7/html/System_Administrators_Guide/sec-Terminal_Menu_Editing_During_Boot.html#sec-Recovering_Root_Password), but they seem to have had no effect.

The password command tells me that the passwords (root and my account) have changed successfully. I can then su into my account, and su back into root with the new password: allowed in fine.

So I run `exec /sbin/init` to continue with boot. Reach KDE login, and cannot login with either password.

I tried to reach the console, but looks like [I need to upgrade my VirtualBox](https://www.virtualbox.org/ticket/51) for that.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Right Ctrl + F-keys will give you console access.  See [here](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/64155/how-to-send-ctrl-alt-fn-to-virtual-box-guest-linux?rq=1)

Comment: Any error messages in `/var/log/secure` from around the time of the login failure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [instructions](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/7/html/System_Administrators_Guide/sec-Terminal_Menu_Editing_During_Boot.html#sec-Recovering_Root_Password) you followed appear to have a typo in the `mount -o remount, rw /` line.  There should not be a space after the comma.  The corrected line should read:

```
mount -o remount,rw /
```

If you entered it with the space as indicated in the document, the `passwd` command will not change the `root password` because the system is still in a `read-only` state.